# What is the best way to type-check the configuration for vscode extension?

Tags: typescript, schema, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a vscode extension that defines a bunch of items in `"configuration"` contribution point in `package.json`.
For example:

```
{
    "configuration": {
        "title": "My extension config",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "my-ext.path-to-some-binary": {
                "type": ["string"],
                "default": "/default/path",
                "description": "Path to some binary, this must be a string and nothig else!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I read the configuration from my extension I am not guaranteed to get `string` type from specified configuration value at runtime.

```
const value: unknown = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("my-ext").get("path-to-some-binary");
if (typeof value !== "string") {
    console.error("User you are crazy!");
}
```

And type checking each configuration value gets very tedious. Why vscode doesn't have an API to deal with invalid values in `settings.json` if it has a type schema defined in `package.json`? And what is the best way to match the config values at runtime to the schema defined in `package.json` without doing it manually or repeating the schema in code using some npm package like [`yup`](https://npmjs.com/package/yup) or [`joi`](https://npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi)?

I know that `vscode-cpptools` has [some custom handwritten code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Extension/src/LanguageServer/settingsTracker.ts#L86) for matching the config values to schema defined in `package.json`, but that seems too messy.

Comment: Hm, I wouldn't really bother, as long as you defined the correct `type` in contributions, the user will already get a warning about it: https://i.imgur.com/6sRxOHh.png